# Tabbing back and forth between destination anchors in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I've got a bit of a tabbing issue with IE from versions 6 - 8 ( still untested in 9, but I'm hoping one fix will fix them all )...

I have a page with a little tool on it that has help icons that when clicked navigate further down the page to a glossary to describe what each piece of the tool does. Each of the paragraphs in the glossary area have a "return to top" button that is linked to the specific help icon that was originally selected.

Here is some of the code.

First, the table that contains the tool, which I have removed because it is not a part of the bug. This section is just a header for the tool:

```
  <table class="timeCardTable">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>
        <span>Start</span>
        <a href="#startTime" name="startTimeIcon" id="startTimeIcon" class="helpIcon">
            <img src="images/helpIcon.png" width="16" height="16" title="Start tooltip." alt="Start tooltip." />
        </a>
    </th>

    <th>
        <span>End</span>
        <a href="#endTime" name="endTimeIcon" id="endTimeIcon" class="helpIcon">
            <img src="images/helpIcon.png" width="16" height="16" title="End tooltip." alt="End tooltip." />
        </a>
    </th>

    <th>
        <span>Length</span>
        <a href="#length" name="lengthIcon" id="lengthIcon" class="helpIcon">
            <img src="images/helpIcon.png" width="16" height="16" title="Length tooltip." alt="Length tooltip." />
        </a>
    </th>

    <th style="display: none;">
        <span>Eating Period</span>
        <a href="#eatingPeriod" name="eatingPeriodIcon" id="eatingPeriodIcon" class="helpIcon">
            <img src="images/helpIcon.png" width="16" height="16" title="Eating period tooltip." alt="Eating period tooltip." />
        </a>
    </th>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now below the tool are the corresponding anchors that these a.helpIcon tags are all pointing to:

```
  <div class="glossaryContent">

<h2 style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); ">Glossary</h2>

<a name="startTime"></a>
<h3 style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); ">Start Time </h3>
<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed quam eu est mattis faucibus. Pellentesque eu sapien purus. Donec tincidunt, nibh id sagittis commodo, mauris ipsum pharetra tellus, ut mattis felis lorem vel mi. Quisque massa lacus, ultrices eu consectetur suscipit, pellentesque et nibh. Phasellus imperdiet consequat neque sit amet ullamcorper. Duis et libero ac massa feugiat venenatis. Integer pulvinar molestie metus sed molestie. Vivamus scelerisque, neque at accumsan sollicitudin, diam tellus venenatis lorem, ac tempor massa velit non massa. 
    <br />
    <a href="#startTimeIcon">top</a>
</p>

<a name="endTime"></a>
<h3 style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); ">End Time </h3>
<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed quam eu est mattis faucibus. Pellentesque eu sapien purus. Donec tincidunt, nibh id sagittis commodo, mauris ipsum pharetra tellus, ut mattis felis lorem vel mi. Quisque massa lacus, ultrices eu consectetur suscipit, pellentesque et nibh. Phasellus imperdiet consequat neque sit amet ullamcorper. Duis et libero ac massa feugiat venenatis. Integer pulvinar molestie metus sed molestie. Vivamus scelerisque, neque at accumsan sollicitudin, diam tellus venenatis lorem, ac tempor massa velit non massa. 
    <br />
    <a href="#endTimeIcon">top</a>
</p>

<a name="length"></a>
<h3 style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); ">Length </h3>
<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed quam eu est mattis faucibus. Pellentesque eu sapien purus. Donec tincidunt, nibh id sagittis commodo, mauris ipsum pharetra tellus, ut mattis felis lorem vel mi. Quisque massa lacus, ultrices eu consectetur suscipit, pellentesque et nibh. Phasellus imperdiet consequat neque sit amet ullamcorper. Duis et libero ac massa feugiat venenatis. Integer pulvinar molestie metus sed molestie. Vivamus scelerisque, neque at accumsan sollicitudin, diam tellus venenatis lorem, ac tempor massa velit non massa. 
    <br />
    <a href="#lengthIcon">top</a>
</p>
```

Now the problem I seem to be having with this is that every browser deals with tabbing through these things differently. In Chrome, if you tab over the first "help icon" - the anchor tag where name="startTimeIcon" - and hit enter, it brings you down to the "start time" area no problem. Hitting tab again brings you back up to the help icons above, focusing on the NEXT icon in the tab order, which would be the anchor tag with the name "endTimeIcon". This is *exactly* how the client wants it to work, as this is one of their accessibility requirements.

In IE, however, if you select any of the anchors at the top, startTimeIcon, endTimeIcon, or lengthIcon, hit enter to go down to the corresponding anchor, then hit tab again, it always defaults back to the startTimeIcon, instead of going to the next help icon. Even if you selected the lengthIcon ( last in the list ), hitting tab again will bring you right back to startTimeIcon.

I have no idea how to even approach this, though I'm fairly sure it's a bug with the way IE handles tab order, but this is a massive issue for the client as the site needs to be 100% screen reader friendly and navigable by tabbing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

grammar

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting something a bit better going after a few hours of hacking away at this. By adding an id the same as the name attribute to each of the helpIcon anchors and adding an href  of "#" to the destination anchors, the tabbing corrected itself in a manner the client deemed acceptable. If I hit enter on one of the help icons, the site now navigates to the appropriate destination, where another hit of tab navigates to the corresponding "return to top" link underneath the description, which then returns the user to the last selected help icon, allowing the user to tab to the next one in the right order. This also happens to be the way it worked in Firefox all along.

Cheers